# Enterprise Architect Reverse Engineering: 'Unexpected symbol' error

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to generate a class diagram, using reverse engineering, but the following is happening:

> There was an error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\Meus documentos\EA_Documentos\Modelos\Environment\class\Factory.h  on line 11.  Unexpected symbol: ISIMFactory
>   You may need to define a language macro.
>
> There was an error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\Meus documentos\EA_Documentos\Modelos\Environment\class\Model.h  on line 99.  Unexpected symbol: ISIMModel
>   You may need to define a language macro.

There are many more of these.

This is the corresponding code in `CSIMEnvironmentModel.h`

```
class SIMMDLENVv01_EXPORT CSIMEnvironmentModel // line 99
: public ISIMModel
, public ISIMEventSource
, public ISIMScheduledModel
, public ISIMExecut
, public ISIMPublisher
{
public:

    CSIMEnvironmentModel(const std::string &a_modelType);
virtual ~CSIMEnvironmentModel(void);
```

and `CSIMEnvFactory.h`

```
class SIMMDLENVv01_EXPORT CSIMEnvFactory // line 11
: public ISIMFactory
{
public:
    CSIMEnvFactory();
    virtual ~CSIMEnvFactory(void);
    std::vector<ISIMModel*> InstanceModel(const std::string &a_modelType, const    std::string &a_conf);
};
```

What's the reason for this error message?

Comment: Can you include the error and code in your question.

Comment: Please put code and error inside your question and don't try to force them following external links (many people here wouldn't do that anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains usage of a macro definition (`SIMMDLENVv01_EXPORT`) that isn't part of EA's standard macro definitions (there's whole a lot of them covering ATL and MFC mostly).
You'll need to add additional ones under '[Settings->Language Macros](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/languagemacros.html)' (as the hint in the error message suggests).

**NOTE**
Use the syntax `MACRO()` when declaring macros that were `#defined` to receive any number of arguments.

If you're trying to reverse engineer framework libraries like Qt or alike, you'll need to set many of these that you're able to reverse engineer the code without getting errors. 
May be you should think of a different strategy to reference these types and classes in your model then.
Another workaround might be to solely preprocess all the code you want to import first, and import from the preprocessed results.

Comment: Hi,

Hi,

I need define the language macro ISIMModel using EA- Enterprise Architect?

How to do it? I am beginner user of EA

Comment: Goto that menu entry I've mentioned ([see here also](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/languagemacros.html)).

Comment: @David Also **Note**: You don't need to provide a macro definition of `ISIMModel` (as you mentioned in the EA User forum) but rather for `SIMMDLENVv01_EXPORT`!

Comment: I defined the language macro to ISIMModel, but now this error occurs. See please. 

    There was an error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\Meus documentos\EA_Documentos\Modelos\Environment\class\CSIMEnvFactory.h  on line 12.  Unexpected symbol: { 
You may need to define a language macro. 
There was an error parsing C:\Documents and Settings\Meus documentos\EA_Documentos\Modelos\Environment\class\CSIMEnvironmentModel.h  on line 99.  Unexpected symbol: , 
You may need to define a language macro.

Comment: @David See my note from the comment before: You need to setup a macro definition for `SIMMDLENVv01_EXPORT`!!

Comment: Hi,

That's what I'm trying to do, but how I do it?
I went to "Settings" -> "Macros Processors ..." and added "SIMMDLENVv01_EXPORT" but the error continue.

Comment: @David May be you have to set additional macros used by this stuff. Do you get exactly the same errors as before?

Comment: Hi @g-makulik ... I added "SIMMDLENVv01_EXPORT" but this error:     
There was an error parsing Environment\class\CSIMEnvFactory.h  on line 12.  Unexpected symbol: { 
You may need to define a language macro. 
There was an error parsing Environment\class\CSIMEnvironmentModel.h  on line 99.  Unexpected symbol: , 
You may need to define a language macro.

Comment: In my code was so: #include "SIMModelInterfaces\ISIMFactory.h" but the directory does not have this "ISIMFactory.h"

I have "CSIMEnvFactory.h" ... can this be?

Comment: Unresolvable includes shouldn't bother EA's C++ parser at all. Again: You have to setup these definitions in EA, whenever you want the parser to skip a text that would spoil the 'normal' c++ syntax. Can't tell anything about your includes.

Comment: _'CSIMEnvFactory.h on line 12. Unexpected symbol'_ Did you also already remove that erronous definition for the `ISIMModel` (`ISIMFactory` resp.) you made before!?!

Comment: Thank so much!!! It was just that I had forgotten to remove the previous settings ....Thank you very much!!! :)